# MySQL: variable doesn't expand in SELECT statement in stored function

Tags: mysql, function

I'm trying to write MySQL function like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION getVal(col varchar(50), xid int, reverse boolean) RETURNS double
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    declare res DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT col INTO res FROM col WHERE id = xid;
    IF(revrese = 1) THEN
        RETURN 1 - res;
    END IF;

    RETURN res;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

However when I execute it like this:

```
SELECT getVal("size", 1, 0);
```

The variable `col` does not expand and the query returns error that table 'col' doesn't exist - which it really doesn't. How can I make this code work properly?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that `SELECT` query?

Answer (score 2):

You have to work with prepared statements to build your statement on the fly.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION getVal(col varchar(50), xid int, reverse boolean) RETURNS double
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    declare res DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', col, ' INTO res FROM ', col, ' WHERE id = ', xid);

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    IF(reverse = 1) THEN
        RETURN 1 - res;
    END IF;

    RETURN res;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This would be awesome if only MySQL allowed dynamic SQL in stored procedures. As I just found out it doesn't and trying to run your code results in:  "Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger".

Comment: @JanKoutný, in stored *procedures*, it does.  But not functions or triggers.  You can call a stored procedure from within a stored function but in that context, dynamic SQL is also not allowed.